# Declaring variable range to select a specific data set

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following codes in order to select a variable range. My Code looks like this but it is highlighted in red with an error: Compile Error expected list separator or ).

```
Sub timestamp_upload()
Dim count4, dcount, dcount2 As Long
Dim user1 As String

user1 = Workbooks("Personal Billed Unbilled Tracker.xlsx").Worksheets("Billed Revenue").Range("L1").Value
count4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeStamp").Range("C1").Value


ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=counta(C[-4]:C[-4])"
dcount = Workbooks("Time Stamp.xlsx").Worksheets("TimeStamp Data").Range("E1").Value

If dcount >= 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeStamp").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeStamp").Range("A2:B" & count4).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Time Stamp.xlsx").Worksheets("TimeStamp Data").Activate
Workbooks("Time Stamp.xlsx").Worksheets("TimeStamp Data").Range("A" & dcount + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("C" & dcount + 1).Select
dcount2 = Workbooks("Time Stamp.xlsx").Worksheets("TimeStamp Data").Range("E1").Value
**range("C & dcount+1:"C & dcount2").select**


End If
End Sub
```

Please Help. Problem with the ** line

Comment: You are missing some quotes. It should be Range("C" & dcount+1 &":C" & dcount2).Select

Comment: I knew I was missing something small..... Thanks Very Much